# Find the sequence number and subnumbers

Tags: perl

I have an array like:

```
 my @tests = qw(1-1 1-2 1-3 1-5 2-1 2-2 2-4 3-1 3-2 4-1 4-2 6-1 6-2);
```

I need to validate the sequence for both number (`1`) and subnumber (`1-1`) subnumber means after -(hyphen) please consider as.

Expected output: `Missing numbers 1-4, 2-3, 5`

My code is below; where am I making a mistake?

```
my @tests = qw(1-1 1-2 1-3 1-5 2-1 2-2 2-4 3-1 3-2 4-1 4-2 6-1 6-2);

my %sub_numbers;

foreach my $test (@tests) {
    $sub_numbers{$test} = 1;  # Mark sub-number as present
}

my ($min, $max) = get_min_max_sub_numbers(\@tests);

my @missing_sub_numbers;

for my $i ($min..$max) {
    for my $j (1..5) {
    my $sub_number = "$i-$j";
    unless ($sub_numbers{$sub_number}) {
        push @missing_sub_numbers, $sub_number;
    }
    }
}

my @filtered_missing_sub_numbers;

foreach my $missing_sub_number (@missing_sub_numbers) {
    my ($number) = split('-', $missing_sub_number);
    my $previous_sub_number = ($number - 1) . "-" . substr($missing_sub_number, 2);
    my $next_sub_number = ($number + 1) . "-" . substr($missing_sub_number, 2);
    unless ($sub_numbers{$previous_sub_number} || $sub_numbers{$next_sub_number}) {
    push @filtered_missing_sub_numbers, $missing_sub_number;
    }
}

if (@filtered_missing_sub_numbers) {
    print "Missing sub-numbers: " . join(", ", @filtered_missing_sub_numbers) . "\n";
} else {
    print "No missing sub-numbers found.\n";
}

sub get_min_max_sub_numbers {
    my ($tests_ref) = @_;
    my ($min, $max) = (undef, undef);

    foreach my $test (@$tests_ref) {
    my ($num) = split('-', $test);
    $min = $num if !defined($min) || $num < $min;
    $max = $num if !defined($max) || $num > $max;
    }

    return ($min, $max);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use hashes to remember what numbers and what tuples of numbers you've seen.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use List::Util qw{ min max };

my @tests = qw(1-1 1-2 1-3 1-5 2-1 2-2 2-4 3-1 3-2 4-1 4-2 6-1 6-2);

my %seen;
for my $tuple (@tests) {
    my ($first, $second) = split /-/, $tuple;
    undef $seen{$first}{$second};
}
my $min = min(keys %seen);
my $max = max(keys %seen);

my @missing;
for my $i ($min .. $max) {
    if (exists $seen{$i}) {
        my $s_min = min(keys %{ $seen{$i} });
        my $s_max = max(keys %{ $seen{$i} });
        for my $j ($s_min .. $s_max) {
            push @missing, "$i-$j" unless exists $seen{$i}{$j};
        }
    } else {
        push @missing, $i;
    }
}

say join ', ', @missing;
```

Comment: Really awesome +1. I am in lack of using in hashes. I will Try to code/learn this hash codings.

Comment: The spec is unclear on how to set the minimum. You can use `1` instead of `min(...)`. Is `1-2` missing, too? Then we need to obtain the `max` over all the values `my $s_max = max(map keys %{ $seen{$_} }, keys %seen);`.

Comment: There's nothing about "subsubnumbers" in the OP.

Comment: @ikegami check my answer with an approach to solve the problem for tuples  with more than 2 elements.

Comment: Oh, thought I had seen x-y-z

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this is to transform the tuples to an AoA structure, then iterate over that to produce the output. The following solution works for structures of arbitrary depth:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @tests = qw(1-1 1-2 1-4 1-5 2-1 2-2 2-3-1 2-3-3 2-4 3-1 3-2 4-1 4-2  6-1 6-2);

my $elements = [];

for my $test (@tests){
    my $subelem = $elements;
    my (@indices) = split('-',$test);
    while (my $i = shift @indices){
        # do we have an [] for the next sub-level?
        # if so, keep it ([] is always true)
        # if not, assign [] if needed (@indices left)
        # otherwise assign 0 (false) which will be replaced
        # by [] in another iteration if necessary
        # 0 marks this entry as present:
        # we check for definedness in sub process() below
        $subelem->[$i] ||= @indices ?  [] : 0;
        $subelem = $subelem->[$i];
    }
}

my $out = '';
process(\$out,'',$elements);

print ($out ?  "Missing sub-numbers: " : "No numbers missing");
say $out;

sub process{
    my ($outref,$prefix,$aref) = @_;
    for my $i (1.. $#$aref){
        if (ref $aref->[$i]){
            process($outref,$prefix."$i-",  $aref->[$i]);
        }
        elsif (!defined  $aref->[$i]) {
            $$outref .= "$prefix$i ";
        }
    }
}

# Missing sub-numbers: 1-3 2-3-2 5
```

Comment: Superb+1.... Could you please explain `$subelem->[$i] ||= @indices ?  [] : 0;` this line. I didn't understand clearly.

Comment: See [||=](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Assignment-Operators) and [?:](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Conditional-Operator) for the documentation of the operators used. I also added comments to the code.

Comment: Great work +1...